# Angular class members are somehow common to all objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
define([], function(){
   function MyClass(Dependency1, Dependency2){
       var private1;
       // Ctor
       function MyClass(param1){
           private1 = param1;
       }
   }

   MyClass.prototype.someMethod(){...}
}
```

So here is my problem - when I instanciate 2 object of class MyClass, the supposed to be private1 field is common to both instances. If one instance change the field, it changes also in second one. If I change it to this.private1, it is specific to each instance, but then it is not private.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking here, currently it is so unclear what you're asking. `the supposed to be private1 field is common to both classes` which classess? you have only one class and of course objects created from this class have private1 property.

Comment: I updated the question so it is clearer now, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you just simply change it like this your problem will be solved,

```
define([], function(){
   function MyClass(Dependency1, Dependency2){
       var private1;
       // Ctor
       function MyClass(param1){
           this.private1 = param1;  //look how I access the object's property
       }
   }

   MyClass.prototype.someMethod(){...}
}
```

Anyway, If I didn't get your intention or ... a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) where we can see the problem, would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The private 1 variable needs to be declared inside the MyClass constructor.

Crockford is your friend:

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: If it's inside the constructor then all the other functions don't know him and he's undefined.

Comment: Yes - it's private. :-)

See the link I posted under "privileged functions" on how to use the private members from within the class.